# How to show and hide divs (multiform tab structure) created dynamically in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to create a tabbed structure using Vue.js programatically. i think it should work by showing the selected div dynamicially and hide the rest
Is there any other efficient way?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Comment: I could have 100-1000 divs how can i use v-if or v-else-if in all of them?

Comment: You could definitely have that many but it's a shame we can't see any in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `v-if` or `v-show` on the div and then you can have it accept a function that evaluates the dynamic data like so:

```
<div v-for="item of items">
   <div v-if="shouldDisplay(item)">{{item}}</div>
</div>
...
methods: {
   shouldDisplay(item){
      if (item...){ //fulfils some condition
           return true
       } else {
       return false
    }
```

As per @Phils suggestion you could also create the array as a computed property that filters out what you need:

```
computed: {
   filteredArray(){
     return items.filter(item => //some condition)
    }
```

Comment: Executing methods from your templates is very inefficient. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

Comment: @Phil you don't have much of a choice when dynamically generating data, the other option would be to create 100-1000 computed properties not very performant either.

Comment: Or just a single computed property that returns a filtered array

Comment: Depends a lot on the data structure, it is possible to do that, personally I have never found any lagging when putting a method in the template iteration.

Comment: I understand this shouldDisplay(item) and my condition is onclick, like we do in jquery how to do that in vue.

Comment: not sure I get you, on click of what? what needs to happen to determine what to display? In vue you can just write @click="someFunc"

Comment: like i have <div id="a" ></div><div id="b"></div><div id="c"></div>, when i click on div with id=a i want it active rest hidden and div can be of any number

Comment: simplest thing imo is to put a `display` property on your "item" and toggle that based on click, then you only display if `item.display === true` or just `item.display`

Comment: on same click i want to display that particular div and hide all other div. how can i do it with one single  property?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to acheive

Answer (score 0):

I did it with very basic code of jquery by calling function with its unique index value and show/hide them on basis of their ids:

```
   methods: {
        changeview(index){

            var id=Number(index)+Number(1);

            $( "#hotel"+id ).show();

            for( var i=0 ;i<this.location.length; i++){
                if(i!==id){

                    $( "#hotel"+i ).hide();
                }
            }
        },}
```